# Rebuild Powerpoint Animation to Android App

Tags: android, animation, powerpoint, parallax

im not good in android animations but so far I did all the stuff with Constraint Layout and get most of the Animations done.

I recently saw a youtube video about Powerpoint Parallax Animation, which has a stunning good animation I want to try for my new Splash/Intro

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDIGQ58DaLU

Is there a chance to build a similar animation in Android? In my opinion it would be nice to copy the background fill that is applied to the shapes - so I do not need to cut my picture into pieces

Comment: This forum is for programming questions. Please post your question at answers.microsoft.com or SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution. Put it on Github
https://github.com/FlorianMarsch/android-parallax-intro

Base part of the solution is using Matrix on the shapes with the same image as at the background

[image: Done it anyway]